# parsing json in ocaml

Tags: json, ocaml

I have a json file that i am trying to parse to ocaml/ reasonml. what im trying to do is to parse json file to OCaml data type so it can be used in OCaml written program.

```
[
  {
    "context": "str.substr,str.substr",
    "rule": [
      "C_1"
    ],
    "prob": [
      1.0
    ]
  },
  {
    "context": "Var,C_1",
    "rule": [
      "C_0"
    ],
    "prob": [
      1.0
    ]
  },
  {
    "context": "0,str.substr",
    "rule": [
      "2"
    ],
    "prob": [
      1.0
    ]
  },
  {
    "context": "str.++,C_1",
    "rule": [
      "C_1"
    ],
    "prob": [
      1.0
    ]
  },
  {
    "context": "Var,str.replace",
    "rule": [
      "C_2"
    ],
    "prob": [
      1.0
    ]
  },
  {
    "context": "str.replace,_",
    "rule": [
      "str.replace",
      "Var"
    ],
    "prob": [
      0.8571428571428571,
      0.14285714285714285
    ]
  },
```

but i am getting "some record field are undefined" error
the code is

Is my code problem or the json file is?

```
type json = {
  context : string;
  rule : string;
  prob : int;
}

let context_json c = 
  {
    context = c |> member "context" |> to_string;
  }

let rule_json r = 
  {
    rule = r |> member "rule" |> to_string;
  }
let parse_context c =
  try context_json c
  with Type_error (s, _) -> failwith ("Parsing error: " ^ s)

let load () =
  let e = Yojson.Basic.from_file "sorted.json" in
  e |> member "context" |> to_list |> List.map context_json
```

Comment: Cross-posted in https://www.reddit.com/r/ocaml/comments/nwatjk/parsing_json_with_to_ocaml_undefined_error/

Comment: Please don't alter the question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead just _add_ information to it, although you should also only ask one question per post. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this function:

```
let context_json c =
  {
    context = c |> member "context" |> to_string;
  }
```

I don't see a definition for `member` anywhere in your code. However, if we assume that the expression `c |> member "context" |> to_string` is valid, then the result of this function is a record with just one field named `context`. But your record type has three fields. You need to define values for all the fields of a record. That's what the compiler is telling you.

If the other fields are always the same you can define the function roughly like this:

```
let context_json c = 
  { rule = "";
    context = c |> member "context" |> to_string;
    prob = 0;
  }
```

Note that you've defined your record type with immutable fields. So you won't be able to change these values later.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. after changing the code i have error on to_list |> List.map context_json.  expression was expected of type 'a list, what does it mean?

Comment: how do we define member? sorry i'm beginner in ocaml and yojson. thanks for the reply.

Comment: OK, now I see that you're using Yojson. I don't know anything about Yojson, sorry. But if `member` is defined by Yojson, you probably need to specify a module as you did for `Yojson.Basic.from_file`.